# Howto get filename from which class was included in PHP

Tags: php, include, filenames

I understand that the question is rather hard to understand, I didn't know how to ask it better, so I'll use this code example to make things more clear:
If I have the following files:

test.php:

```
<?php
 include('include.php');
 echo myClass::myStaticFunction();
?>
```

include.php

```
<?php
 __autoload($classname){
  include_once("class/".$classname.".php"); //normally checking of included file would happen
 }
?>
```

class/myClass.php

```
<?php
 class myClass{
  public static function myStaticFunction(){
   //I want this to return test.php, or whatever the filename is of the file that is using this class
   return SOMETHING;
  }
?>
```

the magic FILE constant is not the correct one, it returns path/to/myClass.php

Comment: I have to ask: why do you want to do such a thing? That's against every possible rule of well written code. If you really need to know the file name pass it as function's argument: `MyClass:myStaticFunction(__FILE__);`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in case you need to get "test.php" see `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

Comment: read the question again:
"the magic FILE constant is not the correct one, it returns path/to/myClass.php"

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using:

```
$file = basename(strtolower($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
```

Comment: So, what if you now use script C, which includes a file that has your first example (A), and then your example includes the second file from autoloading, file (B)

You would have the wrong filename.

Comment: Yes, ok, that's true. However in my case not a problem since I'll always need the first file (C)

Answer (score 2):

I am using

```
$arr = @debug_backtrace(false);
if (isset($arr))
foreach ($arr as $data)
{
 if (isset($data['file']))
 echo $data['file'];
 // change it to needed depth
}
```

This way you don't need to modify the file from which your file is included. debug_backtrace might have some speed consenquencies.

Comment: Thank you for the wonderful debug_backtrace, it's incredible just like java in debug!